# ASP.NET MVC Retrieve Data from Database to DropDownList using Select Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently retrieving data from my Database to DropDownList's now using ViewBag as shown below. I have been told and have seen online that it's best to use Strongly Typed instead of ViewBag when using the Select Tag. Can someone please assist me in getting this to work using a ViewModel/Strongly Typed approach? I would greatly appreciate it!! I'm in the process of learning MVC, I have been used to WebForms and having a hard time wrapping my head around the MVC approach :(

**Employee Model:**

```
    public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EmpFirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EmpLastName { get; set; }

    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public int BldgId { get; set; }
    public Building Building { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeeController:**

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private DataEntryContext _context;

    public EmployeeController(DataEntryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Employees.ToList());
    }

    // Populate Department values to DropDownList
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDepartments()
    {
        var dept = _context.Departments
            .Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = s.DeptId.ToString(),
                Text = s.DeptTitle
            })
            .ToList();

        return (dept);
    }

    // Populate Building values to DropDownList
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetBuildings()
    {
        var bldg = _context.Buildings
            .Select(b => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = b.BldgId.ToString(),
                Text = b.BldgName
            })
            .ToList();

        return (bldg);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        // Load values to DropDownLists for Departments and Buildings
        ViewBag.DeptListName = GetDepartments();
        ViewBag.BldgListName = GetBuildings();

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Employees.Add(employee);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
            //return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = _context.Employees
            .Where(e => e.EmpId == id)
            .Single();

        if (employee == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
            //return NotFound();
        }

        ViewBag.DeptListName = GetDepartments();
        ViewBag.BldgListName = GetBuildings();

        return View(employee);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.DeptListName = GetDepartments();
            ViewBag.BldgListName = GetBuildings();

            _context.Employees.Update(employee);
            _context.SaveChanges();

           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(employee);
    }
}
```

**Employee Create View:**

Below is how I'm retrieving the values to the  tags below for Departments and Buildings.

```
<select asp-for="DeptId" asp-items="@ViewBag.DeptListName" class="form-control">
                <option>Select Department</option>
            </select>

<select asp-for="BldgId" asp-items="@ViewBag.BldgListName" class="form-control">
                <option>Select Building</option>
            </select>
```

**ViewModels:**

```
{
public class DeptViewModel
{
    public int DeptId;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DeptList;
}
```

}

**EmployeeController:**

```
        public IActionResult Create()
    {

        var model = new DeptViewModel { DeptList = DeptList() }; return View(model);

    }
```

Comment: Create a view model containing properties `int DeptId` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> `DeptList` (ditto for `BldgId` and `BldgList`) and initialize it in you GET method and pass the model to the view (refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for a typical implementation)

Comment: Hi Stephen,

That's what I'm having trouble understanding :( How do I create a View Model with those properties? Also, not sure what I need to add to my Create Action Method on the EmployeeController to implement this. Also, how do I add to the DropDownList in the Create/Edit View?

Comment: No, create a separate folder for you view models (so there is no risk of them being associated with your EF context)

Comment: Ok, I created a folder called ViewModels and created a class called DeptViewModel with the code below:


using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataEntryMVCEFCore.ViewModels
{
    public class DeptViewModel
    {
        public int DeptId;
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DeptList;
    }
}

Comment: Hi Stephen,

I updated my code above to show what I have for the ViewModel, is this correct? Then, just need to know what the next step(s) are. I appreciate your help!

Comment: The view model looks fine. Then in the GET method - `var model - new DeptViewModel { DeptList = GetDepartments() }; return View(model);` and in the view `<select asp-for="DeptId" asp-items="@Model.DeptList" class="form-control"><option>Select Department</option></select>`

Comment: I just updated my EmployeeController Create Method with what you mentioned. I had to first add using DataEntryMVCEFCore.ViewModels;

Then I updated the code above under the new EmployeeController above and I get a redline under DeptList() called "The name 'DeptList' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: No it needs to be as per my previous comment - `new DeptViewModel { DeptList = GetDepartments() };` - its your calling your `GetDepartments() method to populate the `DeptList` property. Note also that your view model need properties, not fields (i.e. add `{get; set; }`)

Comment: oh man, I have no clue what you mean by that other than I updated my ViewModel named "DeptVIewModel" to include properties by adding `public int DeptId {get; set;}` and `public string DeptTitle { get; set; }` and `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DeptList { get; set; }`

Comment: Just not sure how to add the rest. Do I need to create a new Controller? Do I use the existing Controller that I have been using called EmployeeController?

Comment: The code just goes inside the existing `Create()` method (and then you need to change the POST method to `public IActionResult Create(DeptViewModel model)` (although the name of the class should be `EmployeeVM` since you creating/editing an `Employee` (and of course it will contain properties for other values of `Employee` that you want to edit such as `FirstName` etc)

Comment: Is there a reason that I can't use my existing Employee Model rather than create a ViewModel? I would like to just pull in the DeptId, DeptTitle, BldgId and BldgTitle to the DropDownList <select> tag when Creating a new Employee and Editing them. If I would happen to need to add more fields to my DB then wouldn't I need to then modify/update the ViewModel to along with the Employee Model?

Comment: You should **never** use a data model when editing. Suggest you read the answers to [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: I never knew that you were not suppose to use the domain model to create, edit and delete from Database :( So it appears that I need to create a ViewModel for Creating, Editing and Deleting instead of my main Employee Model :(

If I make changed to my main Database through my main employee model then I just need to update the ViewModels?

Comment: Still not sure how to populate the Create Method with the DropDownList data. I also have 2 Create Method's it appears I was using one Create Method just for retrieving the DropDownList values and the other Create Post Method to submit the data to the DB.